# Why does my tape measure and my .svg file disagree with how long an inch is?

Tags: svg

I've got this .svg file here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     width="4in"
     height="4in"
     version="1.1"
     viewBox="0 0 4 4">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red"/>
    <line x1="0" y1="0"
          x2="4" y2="0"
          stroke="black" stroke-width="0.01"/>
    <line x1="0" y1="1"
          x2="4" y2="1"
          stroke="black" stroke-width="0.01"/>
    <line x1="0" y1="2"
          x2="4" y2="2"
          stroke="black" stroke-width="0.01"/>
    <line x1="0" y1="3"
          x2="4" y2="3"
          stroke="black" stroke-width="0.01"/>
    <line x1="0" y1="4"
          x2="4" y2="4"
          stroke="black" stroke-width="0.01"/>
    <line x1="0" y1="0"
          x2="0" y2="4"
          stroke="black" stroke-width="0.01"/>
    <line x1="1" y1="0"
          x2="1" y2="4"
          stroke="black" stroke-width="0.01"/>
    <line x1="2" y1="0"
          x2="2" y2="4"
          stroke="black" stroke-width="0.01"/>    
    <line x1="3" y1="0"
          x2="3" y2="4"
          stroke="black" stroke-width="0.01"/>    
    <line x1="4" y1="0"
          x2="4" y2="4"
          stroke="black" stroke-width="0.01"/>    
</svg>
```

I load the file in chrome. I hold a tape measure up to my screen.

I expect to see lines an inch apart. However, the lines are less than an inch

I'm confused. How do I build a .svg file with actual physical dimensions?

Thanks,

Jake

Comment: There's no indication in your example that the lines should be 1 inch. Can your `viewBox` be set to a hard unit measurement of inches?

Comment: Also, strokes *add* to the shape's width. They are not contained *within* the shape's width. Does the .01 for each link account for it all being off?

Comment: Also, is the container rectangle 4 inches when measured?

Comment: oh, when I wrote I expected the lines to be one inch apart, I meant that I expected to hold a tape measure up perpendicular to two parallel lines and the center to center measure should be one inch. The container is NOT four inches, but less, like 90% of the expected value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS unit `"in"` does not represent a real world inch.  Neither on the screen, or when printed.  That may have been the intention originally (I'm not sure), but it certainly isn't the case now.  It would be too difficult now anyway, with screen DPIs changing from monitor to monitor and model to model.

Now the CSS standard just defines one inch as 96 "CSS pixels" (`"1in"` == `"96px"`).

In SVG, One `"px"` is the same as one unit in the current user coordinate system.

So you can't rely on the fact that an element with "4in" will measure four inches on screen, nor in print.  You will need to do tests and work out how to scale your coordinates so that it works for the particular screen or printer you are using.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping for a high precision markup language where I didn't have to test against different screens, printers, and laser cutters, but maybe this isn't it

Comment: @Paul - The 96px is true, but apparently not consistent. Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/ehrfcw98/1/

Comment: nvm, that's apparently an `hr` thing. Setting `box-sizing: border-box;` to the hr makes it same length as svg rect.